# mysql: replacing iterating elements with regular expressions

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to update a table where a filed, called "operatori", contains a set of numbers. 
This is an example. 2,4,4,4,4,4

What I meant to do is to get rid of multiple iteration of the same element of the set and get a cleaner one, like: 2,4.

I have tried with replacing 4,4,4,4,4 with 4, but that works only if I have 5 iterations of the same element and only with number 4.

Numbers are from 0 to 7 and iterations could go from 1 to N.

I think regular expressions can do the trick, but I honestly have many difficulties understanding them.

Do you have any hint?

Comment: you want to lop as an array with that??

Comment: If you're storing a comma-separated list in a relational database, you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: @MattJacob the request was to have multiple data in a ringle record field. I know it's wrong. I opted for having 2 distinct tables, than have a view with a group_concat to show data. I did not succeed in doing my way. The filed set was chosen instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
$str = "2,4,4,4,4,4";
$array = explode(",",$str);
$array = array_unique($array);
print_r($array);
```

output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 4
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I will proceed with php+mysql according your hint. I believe I will encouter problems with the amount of datas, because I have to loop through 18.000 records and the php execution time could eventually run off before completing the update.

Comment: 18000 unique records that have the "operatori" column as a set as explained before.

Comment: you have the possibility of duplication rite??

Comment: Sorry Niranjan, I haven't understood your question.

Comment: ha i got it, i had not read your question completely/. Mark n upvote if u found answer was useful.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the wrong data structure for this purpose.  Typically, you want a junction table with one row per item, rather than storing the items in a list.

But, with only 8 items, you can do the following -- if you don't care about the ordering.

```
select concat_ws(',',
                 (case when find_in_set('0', operatori) > 0 then '0' end),
                 (case when find_in_set('1', operatori) > 0 then '1' end),
                 (case when find_in_set('2', operatori) > 0 then '2' end),
                 (case when find_in_set('3', operatori) > 0 then '3' end),
                 (case when find_in_set('4', operatori) > 0 then '4' end),
                 (case when find_in_set('5', operatori) > 0 then '5' end),
                 (case when find_in_set('6', operatori) > 0 then '6' end),
                 (case when find_in_set('7', operatori) > 0 then '7' end)
                )
. . .
```

This logic can also be used in an `update` statement.